# Something seems to be broken in my belongs_to, has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a data model that looks like this:

A `customer` has `subscription_id` and `setup_id` as parameters. In some cases, `customer` will only have one of the parameters. In other cases, it will have both.

Currently, if I make a new customer through either the subscriptions flow or the setups flow, either `Subscription.last` or `Setup.last` will reflect the most recent customer that was created (with `customer_id` equalling the last customer created)

However, I am having the problem of `Customer.setup_id` or `Custumer.subscription_id` being nil in all cases.

Here's my code from both `subscription.rb` and `setup.rb`:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :customer_id
  belongs_to :customer
end


class Setup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :customer_id
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

And in `customer.rb`:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :stripe_token, :subscription_id, :setup_id, :phone, :plan
  has_one :subscription
  has_one :setup
end
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here but I'd love it if the three data models could talk to each other correctly.

**Edit**: Is it bad that both `setup` and `subscription` belong to `:user` rather than `:customer`?

**Edit 2**: Updated the code of setup.rb and subscriptions.rb to correctly reflect the data model currently. And `customer.rb` is still not recognizing the correct `setup_id` or `subscription_id`

Comment: I'm not seeing the has_many.  You're trying to set up two belongs_to relationships.  If it really is a 1 to 1 based on a foreign key, you should use has_one (and your sub and setup models would have no user_id).  As to the edit: yes, it is bad.

Comment: @numbers1311407 My title was incorrect. The `customer` model has two has_one relationships. Should I change the belongs_to to :customer?

Comment: Yes. Each association needs two declarations - one for each side of the association.

Comment: Looks like your foreign key is the user_id

Comment: @kobaltz So keep it as user_id or change it to customer_id? I changed it to customer_id and tested it and it worked fine

Comment: Perhaps you guys could suggest some code that would help out in this situation?

Comment: customer_id should work just as well. you could also have had a polymorphic model for users that would contain admins, users, and customers. then using a foreign key customer_id would be handy. You should look at the Virtual Attributes on RailsCasts

Comment: Virtual Attributes are way too complicated to solve this problem. This is basic rails connections tuff that I'm blanking on, hoping someone can help me since I've been staring at this for far too long.

Comment: You don't have a subscription_id and setup_id column on Customer, since the foreign keys are in the subscriptions and setup table. Use customer.setup.id and customer.subscription.id, where customer is an instance of Customer, instead.

Comment: @CameronMartin how exactly do I set that up?

Comment: Subscription and setup look like they both hold the same data. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :customer_id
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Setup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :customer_id
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :stripe_token, :phone, :plan
  has_one :subscription
  has_one :setup
end

customer = Customer.first
customer.subscription # Instance of Subscription that belongs to customer
customer.setup # Instance of Setup that belongs to customer
```